# Running MLFlow on GCP VM

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, mlflow

I have installed mlflow on GCP VM instance, 
now I want to access mlflow UI with external IP.
I tried setting up a firewall rule and opening the default port for mlflow, but not able to access it.
Can someone give step by step process for just running mlflow on VM instance?

Comment: Have you succeeded in setting up a firewall rule?

Comment: Yes firewall rule I created, but when I'm trying to spin-off  mlflow by specifying some port, it's not working

Comment: Thanks! Try to check if port open with `nmap` util. To do it run command `$ nmap -Pn EXTERNAL_IP_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE`. If your port still closed update question with your firewall rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've decided to check on my test VM and run mlflow server on GCE VM. Have a look at my steps below:

1. create VM instance based on Ubuntu Linux 18.04 LTS
2. [install MLflow](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/quickstart.html):

   ```
   $ sudo apt update
   $ sudo apt upgrade
   $ cd ~
   $ git clone https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow
   $ cd mlflow
   $ sudo apt install python3-pip
   $ pip3 install mlflow
   $ python3 setup.py build
   $ sudo python3 setup.py install
   $ mlflow --version
   mlflow, version 1.7.1.dev0
   ```
3. run mlflow server on internal IP of VM instance (default 127.0.0.1):

   ```
   $ ifconfig 
   ens4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1460
   inet 10.XXX.15.XXX  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
   ...

   $ mlflow server --host 10.XXX.15.XXX
   [2020-03-09 15:05:50 +0000] [8631] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
   [2020-03-09 15:05:50 +0000] [8631] [INFO] Listening at: http://10.128.15.211:5000 (8631)
   [2020-03-09 15:05:50 +0000] [8631] [INFO] Using worker: sync
   [2020-03-09 15:05:50 +0000] [8634] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8634
   [2020-03-09 15:05:51 +0000] [8635] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8635
   [2020-03-09 15:05:51 +0000] [8636] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8636
   [2020-03-09 15:05:51 +0000] [8638] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8638
   ```
4. check from VM instance (from second connection):

   ```
   $ curl -I http://10.XXX.15.XXX:5000
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Server: gunicorn/20.0.4
   Date: Mon, 09 Mar 2020 15:06:08 GMT
   Connection: close
   Content-Length: 853
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
   Last-Modified: Mon, 09 Mar 2020 14:57:11 GMT
   Cache-Control: public, max-age=43200
   Expires: Tue, 10 Mar 2020 03:06:08 GMT
   ETag: "1583765831.3202355-853-3764264575"
   ```
5. [set network tag](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags) `mlflow-server`
6. [create firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) to allow access on port 5000

   ```
   $ gcloud compute --project=test-prj firewall-rules create mlflow-server --direction=INGRESS --priority=999 --network=default --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:5000 --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0 --target-tags=mlflow-server
   ```
7. check from on-premises Linux machine `nmap -Pn 35.225.XXX.XXX`

   ```
   Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-03-09 16:20 CET
   Nmap scan report for 74.123.225.35.bc.googleusercontent.com (35.225.XXX.XXX)
   Host is up (0.20s latency).
   Not shown: 993 filtered ports
   PORT     STATE  SERVICE
   ...
   5000/tcp open   upnp
   ...
   ```
8. go to web browser http://35.225.XXX.XXX:5000/

[image: mlflow]